# Large centred background image

Tags: css, background

I'm building a website with a 960px design, but the designer has also requested that the page have a *full*-width background photo across it. He has supplied a 2000px image for this.

However, trickily, part of the photo is integral to the navigation of the page, so the image needs to be centred. So I want the left and right edges to overflow out of the viewport. I've tried to do this using CSS, but have failed.

I could do a javascript version to adjust the left margin based on the viewport when the document loads and the window is adjusted, but I expect it may perform badly, particularly on the adjustment. A lot of the target audience of the site have some serious legacy hardware, so will be using slow computers running IE6. Is there a good CSS way of doing this which would perform better?

UPDATE: Sorry, I wasn't very clear in terms of the "full-width" thing. The content of the site is all restricted to a 960px column, *except* this particular image, which should be the full-width of the browser window, even if it is greater than 960px. Using background-position is the method which I've already tried, but if I size the particular div to 2000px wide, then I haven't been able to center the div, whereas if I set it to 100% the background-position:center doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is with `background-position: center top;`, put the 2000px image as a background to a 960px div like this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bg4Hs/7/)

As far as I'm aware this is supported on IE6+

Comment: Thanks very much. Unfortunately, I didn't explain the problem very well - see my update above.

Comment: @SiWilkins Just use two divs then, one "background" div, one content div, overlay the content div on top of the background one

Comment: @SiWilkins Here's a working demo of what I think you want: http://jsfiddle.net/Bg4Hs/9/

Comment: That's spot on. Thanks very much

Comment: @SiWilkins No problem, welcome to stack overflow :) If someone answers your question you can click the tick at the left of it to make it easy for future people to see the fix

Answer (score 0):

Just use background positioning.

```
body {
    background: url(blah.jpg) center top no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this on the image:

```
position: absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:-1000px; /* half the width of the image */
```

However, if part of the image is going to be used for navigation, and it has a fixed 2000px width, i see a lot of tears in your future.

Consider dividing the image into layers that can be manipulated individually.

EDIT: As mentioned by Michael this approach is not good.

Comment: He can use background positioning to position the image.

Comment: It is still a 2000px image that will be used to style actual components of a 960px design site. But you are right, background positioning the image is a better approach and doesn't require a wrapper to hide the overflow.